# I cannot run pyspark/spark locally to read from s3 (as of 2023)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Issue:**
You might want to run some Spark/Pyspark implementation locally to test your logic before deploying to AWS EMR. You are using `s3://` paths locally instead of `s3a://`. This might happen if your design pattern is inconsistent throughout your project with generating `s3` based paths.

You might run into issues such as: `org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"`, or other Java related issues.

You might use localstack or moto or some other mocking library for s3.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Identify what jar files you need. You can do this by visiting Maven and looking for the dependencies.

To connect to AWS S3, from something other than EMR (which should abstract having the jars behind the scene for you), you'll want to use the `aws-java-sdk-bundle` and `hadoop-aws` jars.

For example, if you're using Spark 3.1.3, this ships with Hadoop 3.2.0. So you would want to get the hadoop client jar `hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar`, and identify which `aws-java-sdk-bundle` version it requires. So in the case of `hadoop-aws==3.2.0`, you can use `aws-java-sdk-bundle==1.11.375`.

You'll want to configure your spark instance.

```
SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]")
    .appName("pytest")
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", f"{SPARK_JARS_LOCATION}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar")
    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", f"{SPARK_JARS_LOCATION}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar")
    .config("spark.jars", f"{SPARK_JARS_LOCATION}/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar")
    .config("fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://127.0.0.1:5000")
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    )
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
```

The `fs.s3a.endpoint` is pointing to a mocking server, moto for Python.
The `spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl` key translates `s3://` paths to `s3a://` because that is required for the support AWS s3 connector.

This assumes that you've downloaded the jars manually.
If you want to download the jars direct from Maven, you can use this config option instead of the 2 `extraClassPath` and 1 `spark.jars` config.

```
.config("spark.jars.packages", "aws-java-sdk-1.11.375.jar")
.config("spark.jars.packages", "hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar")
```